# Vol binomial tree

Tags: finance, probability, quants

Suppose that we have a stock $X_t$ valued at 100 euros per share. At each time step the price can go up or down 1 euro with prob $1/2$. Assuming that interest rates are $0$ and the volatility of the asset at time $t$ is defined as

$$vol(X_t)=\frac{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}^2\mid X_t]-\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}\mid X_t]^2}}{X_t}$$
can we derive a closed formula for the volatility depending on $X_t$?

Does $vol$ increases when the price goes up?

Answer (score 2):

The first term under the square is
\begin{align}\frac{(X_t + 1)^2 + (X_t - 1)^2}{2} &=
\frac{X_t^2 + 2X_t + 1 + X_t^2 - 2X_t + 1}{2} \\
&=X_t^2 + 1,
\end{align}
the second term is $X_t^2$. So $$\mathrm{vol}(X_t) = \frac{1}{X_t}.$$